# Redux can't map Array

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, axios

I'm console.log this and it's look perfectly.

This is logger picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSRhV.jpg

Like it show something like this initialState-->case 1 --> case 2

```
renderCoinCards() {
        const { crypto } = this.props;
       console.log('Crypto.data : '+crypto.data+' , '+'Crypto.isFetching : '+crypto.isFetch)
    }
```

But error occurred when I try to map the data.

This is logger picture:https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpNPF.jpg

It's working like initialState --> stop working show me an error

```
    renderCoinCards() {
                const { crypto } = this.props;
               console.log('Crypto.data : '+crypto.data+' , '+'Crypto.isFetching : '+crypto.isFetching+' , '+'Crypto.data.map : '+crypto.data.map((a)=>a.name))
}
```

Could you tell me why and how to fix it.

 Here are source code

Component

```
   class CryptoContainer extends Component {
           componentWillMount(){
             this.props.Fetchcoin()
           }


    renderCoinCards() {
                 const { crypto } = this.props;
                 console.log('Crypto : '+crypto) //logging
     return crypto.data.map((coin,index) => //Add this 
        <CoinCard 
            key={coin.name}
            coin_name={coin.name}
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            price_usd={coin.price_usd}
            percent_change_24h={coin.percent_change_24h}
            percent_change_7d={coin.percent_change_7d}
        />
    ) 
}  
         }


         function mapStatetoProps(state){
           return{
             crypto:state.crypto  
           }
         }

         export default connect(mapStatetoProps,{Fetchcoin})(CryptoContainer)
>
```

Action

```
export default function FetchCoin(){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type:FETCHING_COIN_DATA})
        return axios.get(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com//v1/ticker/?limit=10`)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({type:FETCHING_COIN_DATA_SUCCESS,payload:res.data})
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({type:FETCHING_COIN_DATA_FAIL,payload:err.data})
            })
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
 const initialState = {
        isFetching: null,
        data: [],
        hasError: false,
        errorMessage: null
    }
    export default function (state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case FETCHING_COIN_DATA:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: true,
                    data: null,
                    hasError: false,
                    errorMessage: null
                })
            case FETCHING_COIN_DATA_SUCCESS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: false,
                    data: action.payload,
                    hasError: false,
                    errorMessage: null
                })
            case FETCHING_COIN_DATA_FAIL:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: false,
                    data: action.payload,
                    hasError: true,
                    errorMessage: action.err
                })
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

And store

```
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk,promise,logger)

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    crypto:CyptoReducer
})

const Store = createStore(
    rootReducer,middleware
)

export default Store
```

Comment: What do you expect to be the output in Crypto. Based on your reducer, I don't see a "name" field so the map function is probably working but there is no "name" to return. I would think you should be getting an error of some sort?

Comment: "name" is a key in object from api

Comment: and I want to show the information from this https://api.coinmarketcap.com//v1/ticker/?limit=10

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like `crypto.data` is not an `Array` at all. That's even what we can see in your console. If `crypto.data` will be `null`, you cannot do a map on it.

Answer (score 0):

Before mapping just make sure crypto.data has array length of greater than 0.

You can do this before map function

```
if(crypto.data.length === 0) return null;
```

So it just stops before map function. And if array length is greater than 0  then proceed

Answer (score 0):

Crypto is an array of objects but crypto.data is not defined. You need to change

```
console.log('Crypto.data : '+crypto.data+' , '+'Crypto.isFetching : '+crypto.isFetching+' , '+'Crypto.data.map : '+crypto.data.map((a)=>a.name))
```

to

```
console.log('Crypto.data : '+crypto+' , '+'Crypto.isFetching : '+crypto.isFetching+' , '+'Crypto.data.map : '+crypto.map((a)=>a.name))
```

specifically for mapping, change:

```
crypto.data.map((a)=>a.name)
```

to

```
crypto.map((a)=>a.name)
```